# Jenkins Pipeline - I need to read a file from Jenkins work space and get the string as variable on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I tried using below syntax, but its not showing output

```groovy
def deviceid = readFile('/tmp/env.properties').trim();
echo deviceid;
```

Need a help on this how to readfile and get output string as a variable in jenkins pipeline so that i can inject to next stage of scripts on jenkinsfile

Comment: Try something like: String deviceid= new File("/tmp/env.properties").text.trim()

Comment: @SourMonk that won't work in Jenkins Pipelines. Murali, what isn't working with yoursthis?

Comment: Actually, i need to run shell script and read a output as variable uisng jenkins pipeline
When i ran above command using jenkins pipeline for that echo command i got output as null

Comment: i tried using the below command also
                    def commit1 = sh (returnStdout: true, script: '''cat /tmp/env.properties''')
                    echo "${commit1}"
but still null value gettiing as output, Could  you please help on this

Comment: To me it looks like the file actually doesn't exist or probably is not readable by the user running the Jenkins build agent. Did you check that already?

Comment: Thanks Joerg, Yah actually file not exists,so using my script i had created file then it works fine:-) Thanks